# How to search a directory of directories?

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary, nsdictionary

Here is the directory (in original plist form):

[Directory to be searched](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iChHn.png)

What I'm trying to do is this:

```
func getTaxWithZip(zip: Int) {
    let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("NCZipCode", ofType: "plist")
    let pLData = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path!)
    let dict = pLData as! Dictionary<String, NSDictionary>
    for dict2 in dict {
        for item in dict2 {

        }
    }
}
```

I receive this error on `for item in dict2`:

```
Type '(String, NSDictionary)' does not conform to protocol 'SequenceType'
```

If I try to change it to a Dictionary I get this error:

```
Cast from '(String, NSDictionary)' to unrelated type 'Dictionary<String, NSDictionary>' always fails
```

The goal is to query the plist key "ZipCode" for a zip code.

I'm able to get up to 'let pLData = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path!)' successfully, so no problems with accessing the plist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First look at this line

`let dict = pLData as! Dictionary<String, NSDictionary>`

Which give you a `Dictionary<String, NSDictionary>`, it has no problem

And then the first `for-loop`:

```
for dict2 in dict {
    ...
}
```

When you loop thru the dict, each element dict2 actually is a tuples `(String, Dictionary)`

And then your second `for-loop` is trying to loop a tuples which is not a `SequenceType`

What you need to do it:

```
for (str, dict2) in dict {
    for item in dict2 {

    }
}
```

Or

```
for dict2 in dict {
    for item in dict2.1 {

    }
}
```